# webscript doesn't redirect on error

Tags: javascript, alfresco, status, web-scripting

I have the following webscript ( `disable-affiliate.put.js` )

```
var spaceNode = customSpacesService.getAffiliatedSpace(args.id) ;

if(spaceNode == null){
    status.code = 404;
    status.message = "Can't find affiliated";
    status.redirect = true;
}

spaceNode.addAspect ("cnrps:replaceable");
spaceNode.properties["cnrps:motifReplace"] = args.motif;
var affNonValides = customSpacesService.getEntrepotsDesAffiliesSupprimesErrones();
spaceNode.move(affNonValides);
```

The problem is when the `spaceNode` is null, a status template is supposed to be returned as it always do, but an exception is thrown saying `Cannot call method "addAspect" of null`

So it is obvious that the redirection didn't happen and the script execution go on, Any help please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web scripts engine will execute your script, and *afterwards* will check the `status` variable to understand what to do with the original request. This means that the execution flow of your Javascript *will not end* at the line

```
status.redirect = true;
```

if you look at it, it's really just an assignment and not a method call.
Put the code that uses `spaceNode` in an else branch and you're good to go:

```
var spaceNode = customSpacesService.getAffiliatedSpace(args.id) ;

if(spaceNode == null){
    status.code = 404;
    status.message = "Can't find affiliated";
    status.redirect = true;
}
else {
    spaceNode.addAspect ("cnrps:replaceable");
    spaceNode.properties["cnrps:motifReplace"] = args.motif;
    var affNonValides = customSpacesService.getEntrepotsDesAffiliesSupprimesErrones();
    spaceNode.move(affNonValides);
}
```